# Why do I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'useState' of null?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I use next.js and when I try to use useState hook it gives me an error like:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'useState' of null`
How can I fix it?

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { getLimitedTutors } from "utils/api/tutors"; 

const [tutorLimit, setTutorLimit] = useState(10); // error here

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const { data: tutor } = await getLimitedTutors(tutorLimit ? tutorLimit : 10);
  return {
    props: {
      tutors: tutor.data,
    },
  };
}

// exporting component here
```

getLimitedTutors:

```
export function getLimitedTutors(limit) {
  return cms.get(`/tutors?pagination[start]=0&pagination[limit]=${limit}&populate=*`);
}
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use state in the class / function of your cmponent. React state is used to save data that shall be displayed on screen. That means if you update a variable in your state, it'll update that component. That means you only use state inside your component, not inside the getStaticProps method.

Comment: I tried but still get the same error and I cannot reach `setTutorLimit` when I try to call it iniside another function

Comment: Oh, sorry, I read it wrong. You'll have to use state in the class / function of your cmponent. React state is used to save data that shall be displayed on screen. That means if you update a variable in your state, it'll update that component. That means you only use state inside your component, not inside the getStaticProps method.

Comment: I understood. Then when I place it inside the exported component then I'll not be able to update `tutorLimit` inside the `getStaticProps`, what I'm trying to do is pagination but seems like this is not possible this way :)

Comment: The way you pass data from getStaticProps to a component is by returning the pros and then accessing them from your component. You can read about how to use getStaticProps here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props